# Reading a text file API 15+

Tags: java, performance, android, file

Is there a faster, more efficient way to read a text file than this implementation?

Taking into account phones capabilities:

```
    dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int count = 0;
    try{
        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open("words.txt");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String word;
        while((word = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            dictionary.add(word);
            count++;
        }
        inputStream.close();
        inputStreamReader.close();
        bufferedReader.close();

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double t = ((end - start) / 1000.0);
    System.out.println("Time to read database from file " + count + " items " + t + " seconds");
```

Output:

> Time to read database from file 272403 items 1.112 seconds

Update:
After taking @rolfl advice into account and doing a little more digging this is what I came up with. Any further advice or a tidy up would be very welcome

```
    dictionary = new ArrayList<>(300000);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try{
        inputStream = context.getAssets().open("words.txt");
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buff = new byte[1048576];
    try{
        for(int i; (i = inputStream.read(buff)) != -1; ){
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buff, 0, i);
        }
    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    String[] contents = byteArrayOutputStream.toString().split("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < contents.length; i++){
        dictionary.add(contents[i]);
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double t = ((end - start) / 1000.0);
    System.out.println("Time to read database from file " + dictionary.size() + " items " + t + " seconds");
```

Output:

> Time to read database from file 272403 items 0.708 seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Don't do unnecessary work. You have the `count` variable, but you also have the `dictionary` which has a `size()` method. There's no need for the `count`.
- Android supports Java-7 language features, use them. In this case, the try-with-resources would be your friend.
- guess the size of the ArrayList that yoy may need. In this case, you should be a little generous, and say, pre-size it at 300,000 entries.
- Android now supports (since KitKat) the diamond operator, there should be no need to declare the generic type of the ArrayList as `<String>`.
- I actually like the while loop you have. It is my preferred way of doing line-by-line IO too.

Here's a 'cleaned up' version of your code:

```
private static final int INITIALSIZE = 300000;

....

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
dictionary = new ArrayList<>(INITIALSIZE);
try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open("words.txt")));) {

    String word;
    while((word = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        dictionary.add(word);
    }
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
double t = ((end - start) / 1000.0);
System.out.println("Time to read database from file " + dictionary.size() 
      + " items " + t + " seconds");
```

So, that's a "simplified" version, how to make it faster?

Well, there's a few things. First up, nothing can be for sure unless you test it, so, run some experiments. Things I would try:

1. Specify a buffer-size on the BufferedReader, something large like `1024 * 1024` (a megabyte). This should increase the size of IO's
2. The pre-sized ArrayList will help
3. Consider reading the whole data file in to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and then converting that in one go in to a large String, then splitting the string on line-breaks.

In essence, the larger the IO sizes the better, and the larger the cache sizes are, the better.

Comment: Thanks very much your always very clear and very helpful with your answers :)